# How to display svg image without using Icomoon, Fontello, just like bootstrap-icon library using only html, css

Tags: html, css, icons

For example I have a file **alert.svg**.
I want to display it on the screen in the form of `<i class="fi fi-alert"></i>` via html, css.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is click the file in visual studio code or whatever your code editor is and then copy the `<svg>` code and just paste it in your html code.

or another way is to use the `<img>` tag, like this:

```
<img src="alert.svg" alt="" />
```

But if your question is to actually display the `svg` file with the `<i>` tag... You'd have to make your own `font-family` on icons and then use the `content` in css. Like this:

```
.iconclass:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
   content: "\f843";
}
```